# Is there a way to set a list of bin extents as the index of a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, merge

I have a selection of dataframes for annual records of daily rainfall (ppt_24H) and flood events (Fld). They look like this:

```
               ppt_24H     Fld
01-01-2006     0.2         0.0
01-02-2006     0.6         0.0
01-03-2006     0.0         0.0
01-04-2006     11.5        1.0   
01-05-2006     10.4        0.0
...
```

I have generated DataFrames for each year with a 'groupby' function, splitting between whether or not a flood occurred, and assigning bins for 24H rainfall intervals as follows:

```
my_intervals = np.array([(-0.1,0),(0.0,0.25),(0.25,0.5),(0.5,1),(1,2),(2,4),(4,6),(6,8),(8,12),(12,16),(16,20),(20,25),(25,30),(30,35),(35,40),(40,45),(45,50),(50,np.inf)])

bins = np.append(my_intervals[:, 0], my_intervals[-1, 1])
```

The grouby function is as follows:

```
Y2006 = pd.DataFrame(TM_YEAR06.groupby([pd.cut(TM_YEAR06['ppt_24H'], bins), 'Fld']).size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int))
```

This successfully splits the data telling me how many days on which rainfall was between these selected thresholds was associated with a flood (labelled with '1.0'), or not (labelled with '0.0'). Hooray. However, the indexing varies according to whether there are rainfall events between  each set of threshold. For example, for one year, it looks like this:

```
Fld             0.0 1.0 
ppt_24H         
(-0.1, 0.0]     46  1   
(0.0, 1.0]      161 1   
(1.0, 2.0]      62  0   
(2.0, 3.0]      35  0   
(3.0, 4.0]      11  1   
(4.0, 5.0]      6   0   
(5.0, 7.5]      14  0   
(15.0, 20.0]    2   1   
(25.0, 30.0]    2   0   
(30.0, 40.0]    2   0   
(60.0, 80.0]    2   0
```

This has split the data nicely, but it hasn't included all the bins for which conditions weren't met. I have 20 other years that I need to merge into the same DataFrame which are retuning different indexes and none of them have all the indexes. For example, here's another made up example with different indexes:

```
Fld             0.0 1.0 
ppt_24H         
(-0.1, 0.0]     54  1   
(0.0, 1.0]      144 1   
(1.0, 2.0]      62  0   
(2.0, 3.0]      35  0   
(3.0, 4.0]      11  1   
(4.0, 5.0]      6   0   
(7.5, 10]       14  0   
(15.0, 20.0]    2   1   
(25.0, 30.0]    6   0       
(80.0, 100.0]   2   0
```

So far I have tried using the list in 'my_intervals' to index a blank dataframe 'YALL' to which I could merge, but this does not work. Here is the code for what I have tried:

```
YALL = pd.DataFrame(columns = [0.0 , 1.0], index=[(-0.1,0),(0.0,0.25),(0.25,0.5),(0.5,1),(1,2),(2,4),(4,6),(6,8),(8,12),(12,16),(16,20),(20,25),(25,30),(30,35),(35,40),(40,45),(45,50),(50,np.inf)])
```

This does as I expect, creating a dataframe full of NaN, but when I try to merge Y2006 to YALL, using:

```
Y2006 = YALL.merge(Y2006,left_index=True, right_index=True,how='left').fillna(0)
```

It comes out with this...:

```
Fld             0.0 1.0  0.0_x  1.0_x
ppt_24H         
(-0.1, 0.0)     0   0    0      0   
(0.0, 1.0)      0   0    0      0
(1.0, 2.0)      0   0    0      0
(2.0, 3.0)      0   0    0      0
(3.0, 4.0)      0   0    0      0
(4.0, 5.0)      0   0    0      0
(5.0, 7.5)      0   0    0      0
... and so on...
```

Not what I was hoping for... Any ideas of what I might be able to do?

EDIT:

I managed to figure out that the output index after grouby was a CategoricalIndex, and I worked out how to change my index to a categoical index, using this delightfully inefficient code:

```
CatIndex = pd.Series([(-0.1,0),(0.0,0.25),(0.25,0.5),(0.5,1),(1,2),(2,4),(4,6),(6,8),(8,12),(12,16),(16,20),(20,25),(25,30),(30,35),(35,40),(40,45),(45,50),(50,np.inf)], dtype="category")
idx= pd.Index(CatIndex).astype('category')
YALL = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
```

However now I have encountered an error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

For this line...:

```
---> 30 Y2006 = YALL.merge(Y2006,left_index=True, right_index=True,how='left').fillna(0)
```

The quest continues...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use an [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) as your `bins`:

```
my_intervals = [(-0.1, 0), (0.0, 0.25), (0.25, 0.5), (0.5, 1), (1, 2), (2, 4),
                (4, 6), (6, 8), (8, 12), (12, 16), (16, 20), (20, 25), (25, 30),
                (30, 35), (35, 40), (40, 45), (45, 50), (50, np.inf)]
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(my_intervals)
```

Then do the same operation you did before, and afterwards [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with the `IntervalIndex`:

```
Y2006 = TM_YEAR06.groupby([pd.cut(TM_YEAR06['ppt_24H'], bins), 'Fld']) \
                 .size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
Y2006 = Y2006.reindex(bins, fill_value=0)
```